# OpenCV add() operation results in unexpected dtype and shape

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I wrote the code as follows, and the output results are as follows. As far as I know, the add operation in opencv does not have a value of more than 255 because it performs a saturation operation. However, as in the output below, the number 260 is popped out, and the shape is also outputted strangely. The current version of opencv is 4.8.0.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

x = np.array([250], np.uint8)
y = np.array([10], np.uint8)

print(cv2.add(x, y))
```

**Output**

> [[260.]
> [ 0.]
> [ 0.]
> [ 0.]]

**Expected**

> [[255]]

I've only run this code except for everything else. I run the code through jupyter notebook on vscode, and Google colab has normal output results. I've also run it in py file, and it still has a weird result of 260.

Comment: Can't reproduce. I get the expected output. Using a rather old version (`4.5.1.48`).

Comment: Also, I suggest that, Google colab and jupyter notebook running differ version of opencv than installed on your computer (or on virtual environment)

Answer (score 3):

I have OpenCV v4.9. I can reproduce your observations.

If you want to get the "expected" behavior, make sure the arrays are shaped appropriately:

```
x.shape = (1, 1) # (H, W, C) or (H, W)
y.shape = (1, 1)

z = cv.add(x, y)
print(z.dtype) # uint8
print(z) # [[255]]
```

Since you got a `(4,1)`-shaped result, I think OpenCV interprets your arguments as equivalent to `cv::Scalar`, and treats them as floats. That is just speculation though. The docs will probably explain this in some place that needs to be found first.

Instead of assigning the shape explicitly, your code could also have looked like this (specifying 2D arrays directly):

```
x = np.array([[250]], np.uint8)
y = np.array([[10]], np.uint8)
```

Comment: I agree with you that it is better to specify the shape of arrays, but it seems strange to me that different behavior for different versions of the library, with the same version of numpy. Because as I know opencv uses numpy for such calculations

Comment: of course the library evolves. this is probably a fix for previously unintended behavior. numpy has nothing to do with this. OpenCV does ***not*** "use numpy for such calculations". don't assert things about a library you aren't familiar with.

Comment: Ok, **I'm wrong**. I'm new to opencv lib and I though that for add() the library uses the numpy.ndarray type in such cases. Thanks for correcting my mistake.

Comment: OpenCV's python bindings adapt between cv::Mat and numpy arrays. the calculation is done by OpenCV code. this adaptation has been around for long but it's always evolving based on community feedback.

Comment: Ya, definitely interpreting it as a Scalar. Would be rather surprised if this was documented anywhere -- I remember always having to dig through the code to get some understanding, but I haven't looked at it recently.

Comment: since we have several posters reporting different behavior for different recent versions, this change could be tracked down in recent pull requests. definitely python bindings stuff.