# strange behaviour of cv2.add operation

Tags: opencv

OpenCV says that :
***There is a difference between OpenCV addition and Numpy addition. OpenCV addition is a saturated operation while Numpy addition is a modulo operation.***

see here https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/d86/tutorial_py_image_arithmetics.html

But, I am seeing a strange behavior. Look, instead of showing 255 it's showing 260 ?
Am I doing something wrong ?

```
(py2k23) onkar@DESKTOP-MT8AVE7:~/$ python
Python 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.uint8([250])
>>> y = np.uint8([10])
>>> import cv2
>>> print(cv2.add(x, y))
[[260.]
 [  0.]
 [  0.]
 [  0.]]
>>> print(x+y)
[4]
>>> print(cv2.__version__)
4.9.0
>>>
```

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77897622/opencv-add-operation-results-in-unexpected-dtype-and-shape

Comment: @stateMachine, First, thanks for taking time to reply and helping me. I went through the discussion you pointed out to me, but I don't feel that people are saying anything confidently. Anyways, I have raised a bug on opencv git which is here https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/25165, let's see what they say !

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in cv2 (4.9.0). I tested this with cv2 3.4.18, it works as expected -

```
(myPyTestEnv) onkar@DESKTOP-MT8AVE7:~$ python
Python 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import cv2
>>> x = np.uint8([250])
>>> y = np.uint8([10])
>>> z = cv2.add(x, y)
>>> print(z)
[[255]]
>>> print(cv2.__version__)
3.4.18
>>>
```

Comment: They are saying that it might be a bug , for more information, please follow this link-  
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/25165#issuecomment-1980568719

Comment: it's not a bug. they just included mappings from numpy arrays to `cv::Scalar`. even your example on v3.4.18 (VERY old!) shows that the resulting shape is 2D, so your 1D arrays 
 (not cv::Mat!) have been upgraded to `cv::Mat` somewhere in the process. all you have to do is follow the other question's answer and set appropriate shapes.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks for tkaing time to reply. Let's wait and see what they say. Even I need clarity on this.